# How to resolve a promise from the outside with eventEmitter in nodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, eventemitter

Let me start by saying that I'm very new to Node and possibly made a design error, but I couldn't figure out a better way to do what I want.

I have a function that needs to iterate over an array and for each element in the array it needs to do some async work.

I don't want the caller of the function to proceed until all the elements in the array are processed, so I wrapped my function in a Promise that resolves only when the work on all the elements is finished.

I use eventEmitter **inside** my function in order to signal when that work on 1 element is finished and now we can start working on the next element.

When all elements are processed `array.length==0` and so the promise is resolved.

The problem I'm having is that my event listener is inside the function, and is created each time the function is running. On the other hand, I can't put it outside the function because then I won't be able to resolve the promise for my function.

Can anyone help me figure out how to avoid creating unnecessary listeners and to keep my function working?

I tried using `.once()` instead of `.on()` when creating the listener. It didn't seem to solve the issue...

```
function myFunc(objectToTest, testArray) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        var array = [];

        for (let i = 0 ; i < testArray.length ; i++){
            if (objectToTest.name == testArray[i].name){
                array.push(testArray[i]);   
            }

        }


        eventEmitter.on('done-with-async-work', processArray);
        eventEmitter.emit('done-with-async-work')

        function processArray() {

            if (array.length > 0) {
                let itemInArray = array.shift();
                // some Async function
                auxFunc.asyncFunc(itemInArray).then(function (asyncResult)){
                    // Triggered when asyncFunc promise is resolved
                    eventEmitter.emit('done-with-async-work')
                }
            } else {
                console.log("Finished With All Async work!");
                resolve("Done with work!")
            }

        }

    });


}
```

Comment: You've really just created a recursive function call with eventEmitters, but does the `asyncFunc` rely on the previous result, like a waterfall, or could you just start all the async operations at the same time, and use `Promise.all` to see when they are all done.

Comment: @adeneo The async function does not depend on the previous result. But it spawns a child process, and I don't want it to spawn 20+ processes at once. So sadly I can't use `Promise.all`

Comment: I really don't see the point of using an event emitter here. Does it do anything else than shown in  the question? Then you could simply replace the `emit` call by direct calls to `processArray` - and you really *should* do that.

Comment: "*event listener is created each time the function is running*" - even that won't be any problem. Creating an event listener is cheap. Notice that every time the function is running, also a promise, an array, and at least 4 closures are allocated.

Comment: If you want to wait for each async operation, what you have, perhaps with a recursive function call instead, seems fine to me

Comment: @Bergi "I really don't see the point of using an event emitter here" I'm using the emitter to know when the async operation on 1 item is complete so I can process another item. It's true that the first call can be replaced by a direct call to `processArray`. Also, I'm worried about creating extra listeners, not because of their cost but because they are not destroyed when the function exists, so it's a potential memory leak.

Comment: @Curtwagner1984 No, not just the first call, but *all* calls to `emit`. Especially the ones in the callback of `asyncFunc`.

Comment: @Bergi You are 100% correct!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Promise.all, is very usefully if you want to do multiple things at the same time.  If you want to do things in a linear way you could chain the promises.

So I could make a snippet, I've just done a pretend async function that sqr's it value, and then I add them all up at the end.

You can do more advanced version too, eg. Bluebird Promises have the map function that has a concurrency option.

```js
var somethings = [12,1,33,23,44,22,11,32,12,44,22,32];

function asyncSqr(v) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function () { resolve(v*v); }, 200);
  });
}


function myFunc(a) {
  var sum = 0;
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    function doNext() {
      var next = a.shift();    
      if (!next) return resolve(sum);
      console.log('sending: ' + next);
      return asyncSqr(next).then(function (r) { sum += r; doNext(); });
    }  
    doNext();    
  });
}

myFunc(somethings).then(function (r) {
  console.log('result: ' + r);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be any good reason to use an eventEmitter and on the next line call it, just use `Promise.all` instead, and as `auxFunc.asyncFunc` seems to return a thenable, you could probably just return it in a map

```
function myFunc(objectToTest, testArray) {
    var promises = testArray.filter(function(item) {
        return objectToTest.name == item.name;
    }).map(function(itemInArray) {
        return auxFunc.asyncFunc(itemInArray);
    });

    Promise.all(promises).then(function(results) {
        console.log("Finished With All Async work!");
        // results would be all the results
    });
}
```

If you have to wait for each call, a recursive function that just shifts of array members seems easier

```
function myFunc(objectToTest, testArray) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        var array = testArray.filter(function(item) {
            return objectToTest.name == item.name;
        });

        (function processArray(itemInArray) {
            auxFunc.asyncFunc(itemInArray).then(function (asyncResult) {
                if (array.length > 0) {
                    processArray(array.shift());
                } else {
                    resolve('all done');
                }
            });
        })(array.shift());
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I'll do. This looks like @Keith's answer

Comment: It's somewhat the same principle, they both use recursive function calls, and so does your code actually, it just does it with events instead of direct calls, and this uses an IIFE, while Keith uses a regular function to do the same thing etc. Potato Potato !

Answer (score 0):

EventEmmitters appear to be completely unnecessary here. A standard promise chain will do the job of sequencing async tasks. In fact that is the main *raison d'être* of a promise chain (the other aspect being error handling).

For this job, the pattern works-up as follows :

```
function myFunc(objectToTest, testArray) {
    // first, pre-filter testArray.
    var array = testArray.filter(function() {
        return objectToTest.name == item.name;
    });

    // now use .reduce() to build a promise chain from the filtered array.
    return array.reduce(function(chain, item) {
        return chain.then(function(previousResult) {
            return auxFunc.asyncFunc(item).then(function(result) {
                // Triggered when asyncFunc promise is resolved
                // ... do something with the result ...
                return result; // make this step's result available to next step in the chain (if required).
            });
        });
    }, Promise.resolve(intialValue));
}
```

Taking it one stage further, the filter action can be performed on-the-fly in the reduction - no need to pre-filter.

```
function myFunc(objectToTest, testArray) {
    return testArray.reduce(function(chain, item) {
        if(objectToTest.name !== item.name) {
            // Filter on-the-fly
            // Don't extend the chain at this iteration of .reduce()
            return chain;
        } else {
            // item.name meets the criterion, so add an async task to the chain.
            return chain.then(function(previousResult) {
                return auxFunc.asyncFunc(item).then(function(result) {
                    // Triggered when asyncFunc promise is resolved
                    // ...
                    return result; // make result available to next step in the chain.
                });
            });
        }
    }, Promise.resolve(intialValue));
}
```